# Matrices Spatial puzzle with triangles and squares in lines

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

Try this Raven matrices puzzle:

[image]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/comments/19dpgap/what_is_the_right_answer_and_why/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering my other response was inadequate:

The only other solution I see is

> 2

> The idea is that in each row make the lines of the same shape overlap (sometimes by reflecting the line along the x axis) in the first and second tiles and then you deduct that shape if the shapes overlap or keep the shape if the shape is not present in the line. This will manufacture the result in the last tile. The result should match the results of such overlapping positionally as well as numerically. If in the last tile the line of the shapes is reflected from previous tile the result of the overlapping is reflected too.